# why are my edges and faces not highlighted

Tags: modeling

I am clearly in edit mode, and yet suddenly I select a face but it doesn't highlight. Blender is not showing me my faces, edges or verts in edit mode. What is the problem?[image]

Comment: Have you disabled the [Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html)?

Comment: Not on purpose! I'll look--thanks!

Comment: That was it--thanks!